# Can't load images with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, file, load

Just starting. I'm trying to load image from folder. The html and javascript files are in the same folder as the images but i still can't load them.

```
$(function() { 
$('#main').append('<img src="plus.png" alt="click to see the paragraph" 
id="clickMe" />')
$('#clickMe').toggle(function() {
$('#message').show('fast');
$('#clickMe').attr('src', minus.png);

}, function(){
$('#message').hide('slow');
$('#clickMe').attr('src', plus.png);
});
$('#message').hide();

});
```

Comment: `$('#clickMe').attr('src', plus.png);` should be `$('#clickMe').attr('src', 'plus.png');` and same goes for `minus.png`

Comment: i added '' to both files but it changed nothing. still not loading

Comment: Verify that you image path is correct. If this script is in a file, say, index.html, make sure your images are in the same folder and not in a sub-folder like `images/plus.png`.

Answer (score 0):

By reading the code, I'm not entirely sure what you want this to do.
If the idea is that on page load you display an image, and after you click the image, you want to change it's source and display the `#message`, then this should be working, provided that you have the correct image paths.

```
$(function() { 
  // add the image to element
  $('#main').append('<img src="plus.png" alt="click to see the paragraph" id="clickMe" width="100" height="100"/>');
  $('#main').on('click', '#clickMe', function() {
    // check if message is visible, if so, hide it
    if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
      $(this).attr('src', 'plus.png').removeClass('expanded');
      $('#message').hide('slow');
    }
    // otherwise show it
    else {
      $(this).attr('src', 'minus.png').addClass('expanded');
      $('#message').show('fast');
    }
  });
});
```

EDIT:
The reason why your version isn't working, is because `.toggle()` toggles immediately after the page is loaded, so it hides your message immediately. That's not what you want - what you want is to set an event listener to do the hiding only once you click on the image. Another thing - you do not set image height and width in your example, so this is another thing that might be a problem - your image simply is not showing even though it's loaded.

And yes, you can add classes on the fly. Them being defined in the CSS is not required.

Comment: Hey! Your version works! thx! gonna compare and try do understand why mine isnt working : )

Comment: one thing i dont get, is the hasClass('expanded')
nothing in my code has this class so why is it working ?

Comment: @arkusie With the class you simply add something to distinguish between the two states. It's good that that class does not have any styles associated to it. `if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')` checks whether we should show or hide the text.

Comment: so basically i can add and remove this class on a fly without a need of defining it before? Sorry for my stupid questions, i just started learning on my own, when i save enough im gonna attend to some learning program

Comment: @arkusie I edited my answer. Ask away if something's not clear.

Comment: @arkusie if this helped, can you accept my answer, please?